# Cloud function wait for DB request

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a schedule Cloud function. In this I want to load some stuff from the database and modify it.

The function run but I can't wait for the database Stuff.

May you can see an error and help me...

my code

```
exports.notifysmall = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 15 * * *')
.timeZone('Europe/Berlin').onRun((context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    console.log("#################START RUN################");
    db.collection("user").get().then((snapshot: any) => {
        snapshot.forEach((record: any) => {
            console.log(record.get("name"));
        });
        return true;
    }).catch((err: any) => {
        console.log("#################ERROR################");
    });
    console.log("#################END################");
    return true;
});
```

what I want to see in my log is:

```
#################START RUN################
user1
user2 
user3
#################END################
```

what I so at the moment:

```
#################START RUN################
#################END################
user1
user2 
user3
```

why is this?

Regards and thanks for help
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `get()` method is asynchronous and returns a Promise: the `console.log()`s in the `then()` method are executed only when the Promise returned by the `get()` method is [fulfilled](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). On the other hand the line which prints `END` is immediately executed and consequently will "always" come before the `console.log()`s in the `then()`.

In addition note that you don't correctly return the [Promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining). I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/). **This is a KEY point for Cloud Functions**.

You should therefore do as follows:

```
exports.notifysmall = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 15 * * *')
.timeZone('Europe/Berlin').onRun((context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    console.log("#################START RUN################");
    return db.collection("user").get()   //  <--- See the return 
    .then((snapshot: any) => {
        snapshot.forEach((record: any) => {
            console.log(record.get("name"));
        });
        console.log("#################END 1 ################");
        return true;
    }).catch((err: any) => {
        console.log("#################ERROR################");
        return true;
    });
    console.log("#################END 2 ################");
});
```

---

What you should see with the above code is as follows:

```
#################START RUN################
#################END 2 ################
user1
user2 
user3
#################END 1 ################
```

The line which prints `END 1` will be executed after the other `console.log()`s, as explained above.